# Can I update my password in laravel and mongodb?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, change-password

I am coding in laravel, I have to update my password, I did some coding but it shows this error

> Creating default object from empty value

Here Is My Code In Controller

```
public function passwordChange(Request $request, $email)
    {
        $user = User::find($email);

        $user->password = $request->get('password');
        $user->save();

        return redirect('home');
    }
```

I Have pass email in session

This Is Code Of My Blade File

```
<section id="wrapper">
        <div class="login-register" style="background-image:url(../assets/images/background/pic.jpg);">
            <div class="login-box card">
                <div class="card-body">

                    @if(Session::has('key'))
                        {{Session::get('key')['email']}}
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" method="POST" action="{{ url('reset-password', 'email')}}">
                        @csrf

                        <h3 class="box-title m-b-20">{{__('Recover Password')}}</h3>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="New Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" required placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center p-b-10">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
                                {{__('Set New Password')}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here Is My Route File

```
 Route::post('reset-password/{email}', 'AdminController@passwordChange');
```

Comment: it seem you didn't find any user here User::find($email);   try to put dd after this line

Comment: put your route file code too

Comment: Route::post('reset-password/{email}', 'AdminController@passwordChange');

No I try dd too. I got users

Comment: try after interchange this (Request $request, $email) to ($email ,Request $request ) in controller

Comment: Nope, Still Getting same error

Comment: try dd($email,$user) after find

Comment: I got 2 lines
"email"
null

Comment: i think you got your error

Comment: Ya there's nothing come in $user. But I couldn't figure it our how i solve it?

Comment: @Gaurav, you don't have to change the order of the Request $request variable in the parameter, as it is the object to fetch the items from the source of the request...

John_rees, may I request for a copy or error message of the error?

Comment: @John_rees the "::find()" method of the Collection searches for the "id" or the indicated primary key of your Model, you should try "::where('email', $email)->first()"

Comment: Ya Sure @Noctis17
here Is My Error
 ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Creating default object from empty value

Comment: have you tried my last comment/anwer @John_rees?

Comment: Yes Still Having Same Issue

Comment: what are the fields or columns of your User model? @John_rees

Comment: In User Model
protected $fillable = ['username','company_email','password','role_id'];

Comment: so in your case @John_rees, you may use ::where('company_email',$email')->first() so that you can fetch the email that matches from the form, that should do it

Comment: Actually For Session I use username and email Both Just like this

Session::put('key', ['username' => $user->username, 'email' =>$user->company_email]);

This Is My URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password/email"

Comment: try this tutorial https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/

Comment: Owk, I'll Try It Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `::find()` method of the Collection searches for the `id` or the indicated primary key of your Model, you should try :

```
::where('email', $email)->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you finding the email with `find` method because the `find()` method finds the record by it's `$primaryKey` property. Instead of this, you can do like

```
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first()
$user->password = $request->get('password');
$user->save();
```

I suggest you save the password in the Hash form.
you can use `bcrypt` helper function or you can do it by `Hash::make($yourPassword)`